# Запретить (или переадресовать) запрос https

Tags: linux, apache, ssl

У клиента сервер ubuntu 16.04
Там apache
есть 2 сайта. назовет их test.ru и test2.ru

ssl сертификат настроен только для test.ru

но при заходе на https://test2.ru открывается директория
сайта test.ru
так же при заходе просто на ip сервера по https
тоже открывается директория
сайта test.ru
Необходимо в идеале- запретить
открывать сайт при обращении по айпи хоть по http
хоть по https, выдавать 404.
(сейчас по http по айпи открывается test2.ru по https test.ru)
при обращении по https://test2.ru выдавать 404

вот содержимое файла /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.ru.ssl.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.ru
    ServerName test.ru
    ServerAlias www.test.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.ru
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.ru.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.ru.access.log combined
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/test.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/chain.crt
 <Directory /var/www/test.ru>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

вот содержимое файла /etc/apache2/sites-available/test2.ru.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.ru
    ServerName test2.ru
    ServerAlias www.test2.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test2.ru
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test2.ru.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test2.ru.access.log combined
 <Directory /var/www/test2.ru>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

вот содержимое файла /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.ru.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.ru
    ServerName test.ru
    ServerAlias www.test.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.ru
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.ru.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.ru.access.log combined
 <Directory /var/www/test.ru>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

вот структура директории  /etc/apache2

[image: структура директории /etc/apache2]

Comment: Без наличия сертификата вы не сможете сделать переадресацию с HTTPS. Потому что для отправки команды на переадресацию браузеру с HTTPS хоста, все равно потребуется установка TLS соединения, которое в свою очередь требует валидный сертификат. К тому же переадресация с HTTPS на HTTP недопустима по соображениям безопасности, некоторые браузеры либо выдают предупреждение пользователю, либо вообще запрещают такой тип переадресации.

Comment: Если у вас проблема с test2.ru, то приложите конфиг этого сайта.  Слово `аналогичен` можно трактовать очень широко. Вплоть до того, что у вас там те же самые `ServerName` и `DocumentRoot`

Comment: У меня проблема с test.ru потому что его контент дублируется 3 раза. можно просто

Comment: К тому же переадресация с HTTPS на HTTP недопустима по соображениям безопасности<<<  можно просто запретить https запросы на test2.ru и по айпи? не надо переадресовывать. test2.ru старый сайт будет удалятся

Comment: конфиг тест 2 приложил в вопрос

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Исправил текстом